# PHPExcel - keep the header of a xls Template in the new created one

Tags: php, phpexcel

How can i Keep the Header of a xls template in the new created one?
this the code i use : 
to generate a xls file from the template

```
/** Error reporting */
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
define('EOL',(PHP_SAPI == 'cli') ? PHP_EOL : '<br />');
/** Include PHPExcel */
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';
$inputFileName = './Modele/modele.xls';
/**  Identify the type of $inputFileName  **/
$inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
/**  Create a new Reader of the type that has been identified  **/
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
/**  Load $inputFileName to a PHPExcel Object  **/
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
// PARSING DATA IN SHEETINDEX(0)
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D'.'2', $date);
//PARSING DATA IN SHEETINDEX(1)
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(1);    
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('E'.'2', $date);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.'2', $MED_PRES_NOM);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.'3', $MED_PRES_ADDR);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.'4', $MED_PRES_TEL);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.'10', $MED_PRES_CDBANQUE);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.'10', $MED_PRES_CDVILLE);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C'.'10', $MED_PRES_NCOMPTE);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('E'.'10', $MED_PRES_CLERIB);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.'12', $MED_PRES_NPATENTE);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.'13', $MED_PRES_IDFISCALE);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.'14', $MED_PRES_TYPEASSMALADIE);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.'14', $MED_PRES_REFASSMALADIE);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.'15', $MED_PRES_ICE);
$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5($objPHPExcel);
$objWriter->save('Output/Fac/File-'.rand().'.xls');
```

i tried to find a solution but without success !!

Comment: And what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to copy header of a template to another sheet then check this out:-

```
$workingSheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
//copy sheet
$objWorkSheetBase = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(); 
//clone template sheet to new sheet 
$objWorkSheet1 = clone $objWorkSheetBase;
//set title of sheet
$objWorkSheet1->setTitle('XYZ');
//generate sheet
$objPHPExcel->addSheet($objWorkSheet1);
```